# Como convertir un elemento Element en String (XML)

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, printf, elementos

> **Quiero saber como almacenar los datos que se muestran en el `System.out.printf` en una variable de tipo `String`**

`Estoy trabajando con XML y BBDD.

Quiero Leer un fichero XML y almacenar su contenido en la BBDD.

**Leer Fichero**

```
public void leerFicheroXML() {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder;
        Document doc;
        Alumno al = new Alumno();

        try {
            builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            doc = builder.parse(new File(nombreFile));
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList nodeListGrupo = doc.getElementsByTagName("grupo");
            NodeList nodeListAl = doc.getElementsByTagName("alumno");
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeListGrupo.getLength(); i++) {
                Node nodeGrupo = nodeListGrupo.item(i);

                if (nodeGrupo.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element elementoGrupo = (Element) nodeGrupo;
                    System.out.printf("NOMBRE GRUPO= %s %n", elementoGrupo.getAttributeNode("nombre"));             
                }

            }
            System.out.println();
            for (int j = 0; j < nodeListAl.getLength(); j++) {
                Node nodeAl = nodeListAl.item(j);
                if (nodeAl.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element elementoAl = (Element) nodeAl;
                    System.out.printf("NIA= %s %n", elementoAl.getAttributeNode("nia"));
                    System.out.printf("NOMBRE= %s %n", elementoAl.getAttributeNode("nombre"));
                    System.out.printf("APELLIDOS= %s %n", elementoAl.getAttributeNode("apellidos"));
                    System.out.printf("GENERO= %s %n", elementoAl.getAttributeNode("genero"));
                    System.out.printf("CICLO= %s %n", elementoAl.getAttributeNode("ciclo"));
                    System.out.printf("CURSO= %s %n", elementoAl.getAttributeNode("curso"));
                    System.out.printf("GRUPO= %s %n", elementoAl.getAttributeNode("grupo"));

                    System.out.println();
```

> //Esto es lo quiero conseguri hacer una vez que consiga convertir el
> Element en String
> String nia=elementoAl.getAttributeNode("nia");
> al.setNia(nia);

```
                    bbdd.eliminarAlumno(al);
                }
            }

            

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto no fue escrito por un hablante nativo de español, usé "traductor de Google" para producir esto.

Creo que tiene un problema con sus declaraciones "printf" y un malentendido sobre el valor de retorno del método "getAttributeNode()".

Su cadena de formato espera dos parámetros, pero solo proporciona un valor, el valor de retorno de "getAttributeNode()". Devuelve un objeto "org.w3c.dom.Attr", que tiene un getter para el valor.

Este tipo de problema es la razón por la que es conveniente usar un "editor inteligente" como Eclipse, que le dirá qué tipos de devolución devuelven los métodos y le permitirá navegar en esos tipos. También es útil ejecutar código como este en un depurador, para que pueda recorrer cada línea y ver qué tipo y valor se devuelve.

Comment: Si lo estoy desarrollando en Eclipse, tal ven no me he expresado bien, uso los "printf", como una guía para saber si los valores que se muestran por consola coinciden con los valores que quiero guardar en la Clase Alumno, y dado que ya  conseguí reflejar los valores que deseo ahora tengo que almacenarlos pero no se como hacerlo

Comment: @david-m-karr It would be ideal if you change your answer in Spanish

Answer (score 0):

Para Conseguir guardar los datos del XML y pasar los a String los atributos y luego usarlos en la BBDD.

```
String nia = elementoAl.getAttribute("nia");
                    String nombre = elementoAl.getAttribute("nombre");
                    String apellidos = elementoAl.getAttribute("apellidos");
                    String genero = elementoAl.getAttribute("genero");
                    String ciclo = elementoAl.getAttribute("ciclo");
                    String curso = elementoAl.getAttribute("curso");
                    String insertGrupo = elementoAl.getAttribute("grupo");
                    al.setNia(Integer.parseInt(nia));
                    al.setNombre(nombre);
                    al.setApellidos(apellidos);
                    al.setGenero(convertirStringtoChar(genero));
                    al.setCiclo(ciclo);
                    al.setCurso(curso);
                    al.setGrupo(insertGrupo);
                    
                    bbdd.eliminarAlumno(al);
```

Una vez que lea todo el archivo XML y aquellas ID (Nia) que ya existan en la BBDD, las eliminará caso contrario no.